# Why does my class variable _x don't increase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to describe the class instances of which store quantity of instances of that class. Here is the code:

```
class WeAre:
    _x = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self._x += 1

    @property
    def count(self):
        return self._x

    @count.setter
    def count(self, val):
        return None

    @count.deleter
    def count(self):
        return None

    def __del__(self):
        self._x -= 1    

a = WeAre()
print(a.count)
b, c = WeAre(), WeAre(),
a.count = 100500
print(a.count, b.count, c.count)
del b.count
del b
print(a.count)
```

Here is my output:

```
1
1 1 1
1
```

And I can't understand why class variable *_x* doesn't increase/decrease

Comment: Can you confirm the indentation of the second line?

Comment: Where are you increasing the class variable?

Comment: Inside __init__, isn't it?

Comment: No, that is setting the instance variable _x. The answer that has been posted goes into more depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In constructor you are creating instance's variable which overshadows class variable. Therefor you are always working with object instance's variable.

```py
class WeAre:
    _x = 0  # <-- class variable
                         #       creates     uses
                         #      object var  class var
                         #
                         #          |         |
    def __init__(self):  #          V         V          
        self._x += 1     # same as self._x = self._x + 1
```

That would work:

```py
class WeAre:
    _x = 0

    def __init__(self):
        WeAre._x += 1
```

But you may need to re-think it if you would need to override `WeAre` class.